# When using the class Simon I am giving 2 arguments one is self and other is sound. But, when i am using list I have to give 1 arg why is that?**

Tags: python, oop, parameters, arguments, self

class Cat():
is_lazy = True

```
def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

def walk(self):
    return f'{self.name} is just walking around'
```

class Simon(Cat):
def sing(self, sounds):
return f'{sounds}'

class Sally(Cat):
def sing(self, sounds):
return f'{sounds}'

class Maroon(Cat):
def sing(self, sounds):
return f'{sounds}'

my_cats = [Simon('simon', 4), Sally('sally', 3), Maroon('maroon', 2)]
print(Simon.sing(Simon, 'meow'))
for caty in my_cats:

```
print(f'this is {caty.name} ', caty.sing('meowww'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be an error in the formatting of your answer, it makes it  a bit difficult to read, but I'll try to answer :)

The thing is that `Simon` is a class, whereas all the cats in your list are *instanciations of your classes*.

To make it clearer, it is the same difference between `"meowww"` and `str`: `str` is a class whereas `"meowww"` is an instanciation of the class `str`.

The keyword `self` actually refers to the instance of the class. When you instanciate an object, it calls the method `__init__` and returns an object of type `Simon`, with all the attributes defined in `__init__`.

In your case, you would do `simon = Simon("simon", 4)`, and you'll then be able to only write `simon.sing("meowww")`, because the word `self` in the function will automatically refer to your object `simon`, that has the type `Simon`.

However, when you use it directly by writing `Simon.sing("meowww")`, you haven't created any object of the class `Simon`. So the word `self` can't refer to anything, and you have to provide it yourself.

You had luck in your case: in your function `sing`, you do not use to `self`. So you could have provided anything, and the function would have worked anyway (try it yourself :) ).
If you modify your function `sing` as following though, you'll have a problem:

```
class Simon(Cat):
    def sing(self, sounds): return f'{self.name} says: {sounds}'
```

It'll raise an `AttributeError: type object "Simon" has no attribute "name"` when you try to make Simon sing, because you provide `self` as `Simon`. And as the class `Simon` has not been instanciated, the `__init__` method hasn't yet been called and `self.name` is not yet defined.

If it's unclear, do not hesitate to ask :)